# How do I get CDI to work with quarkus when using a gradle composite build?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, cdi, quarkus, monorepo

I can't get quarkus CDI to work when using a gradle composite build

Gradle 8
Quarkus 2.16.2.Final

Here is my super simple DI code.
First, the Bean I want to inject in the library:

```kotlin
//file: libraries/auth/src/main/kotlin/com/bean/example/auth/AuthTokenProvider.kt

package com.bean.example.auth

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
class AuthTokenProvider() {
    val myToken = "so secure"
}
```

Second, the service I wish to inject the bean into:

```kotlin
//file: services/quarkus-service/src/main/kotlin/com/bean/example/AuthTokenConsumer.kt

package com.bean.example

import com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
class AuthTokenConsumer(val tokenProvider: AuthTokenProvider) {
    fun main(): String {
        return tokenProvider.myToken
    }
}
```

This will fail either when trying to run the app, or when trying to run the included test

```kotlin
//file: services/quarkus-service/src/test/kotlin/com/bean/example/AuthTokenConsumerTest.kt
package com.bean.example

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import javax.inject.Inject

@QuarkusTest
class AuthTokenConsumerTest {
    @Inject lateinit var consumer: AuthTokenConsumer

    @Test
    fun testFn () {
        assertEquals("so secure", consumer.tokenProvider.myToken)
        assertEquals("so secure", consumer.main())
    }
}
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
> Task :services:quarkus-service:test

AuthTokenConsumerTest > testFn() FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at QuarkusTestExtension.java:625
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at AugmentActionImpl.java:335
            Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException at Execution.java:123
                Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException at BeanDeployment.java:1223
                    Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException at Beans.java:440

1 test completed, 1 failed

> Task :services:quarkus-service:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here's the stacktrace for the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1223)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:288)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:148)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:440)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:539)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:276)
    ... 11 more

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:625)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:696)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1223)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:288)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:148)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:440)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:539)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:276)
    ... 11 more

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:335)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:222)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:592)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:640)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1223)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:288)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:148)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:526)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:440)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:539)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:276)
    ... 11 more

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1223)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:288)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:148)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:526)
    at java.base@19.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base@19.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base@19.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.bean.example.auth.AuthTokenProvider and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer():tokenProvider
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.bean.example.AuthTokenConsumer]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:440)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:539)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:276)
    ... 11 more
```

I have included beans.xml under META-INF, as well as ran the Jandex plugin in the build, to no avail.

Here's the project structure:
[image]

Here are the build files:
library gradle.settings.kts:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}


// == Define the inner structure of this component ==
rootProject.name = "libraries"
include(
    "auth",
)
```

library build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    `java-library`
    id("org.kordamp.gradle.jandex") version "1.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc:2.16.2.Final")
}

group = "com.bean.example"
```

Service gradle.settings.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

includeBuild("../libraries")

// == Define the inner structure of this component ==
rootProject.name = "services"
include(
    "quarkus-service",
)
```

Service build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    id("io.quarkus") version "2.16.2.Final"
    id("org.kordamp.gradle.jandex") version "1.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:2.16.2.Final"))
    implementation("com.bean.example:auth")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-core:2.16.2.Final")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc:2.16.2.Final")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin:2.16.2.Final")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson:2.16.2.Final")

    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:2.16.2.Final")
}


group = "com.bean.example"
version = "1.0"

tasks.compileTestKotlin {
    dependsOn("jandex")
}
```

Minimal Reproduction Repo
https://github.com/jcjolley/quakus-cdi-failure-example

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to migrate a large project off of buildSrc to this

Comment: Could you please add the full exception messages? I'm pretty sure they will be quite helpful.

Comment: @Ladicek, I have updated the question with the full error/stacktrace. Thank you!